# eclipse cannot see my package(android). and a lot of No Makefile in package when i make package

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

...@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/aaa$ rosmake
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['aaa']
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['aaa']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/hanbo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120315-145637
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['aaa'] to:
['aaa']
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages aaa.  This may take a few seconds.
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> test_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< test_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package test_ros
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosjava [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosjava  No Makefile in package rosjava
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbagmigration [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbagmigration ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbagmigration
No Makefile in package rosbagmigration
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> aaa [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< aaa [SKIP] No rule to make target None
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 30 packages with 0 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/hanbo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120315-145637

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29802/eclipse-cannot-see-my-package(android).-and-a-lot-of-no-makefile-in-package-when-i-make-package/) by [hanbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1967/hanbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-03-18**:
Please try to clarify your question. What are you trying to do? What steps have you taken? What steps did not result in what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the latest documentation for building here:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/index.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0